# Two-speed controller for DC Fan

Tags: dc, voltage-divider, brushless-dc-motor

I have a notebook fan running on 5VDC 0.2A (1W) and a USB powerbank as a battery source (5VDC 7200mAh).

This is the fan I have: http://www.ebay.com/itm/191872144970?_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

I want to run this fan on two different speeds/voltages but I have not decided at what speeds/voltages right now.

This is the schematic that I have come up with:
[image: Fan Controller Schematic]

I have no idea wether the resistences are correct or not.
The reason I have two potentiometers are because I MIGHT want to adjust the two different speeds at a later time (different fan perhaps).

So, I need help deciding if this is the correct way of doing it and if the components are correct?

EDIT: Updated the fan specs.

Comment: Are you gonna use this on a computer? While this might work for a while, the fan might not start up reliably when it wears off a bit.. so if you need reliability, this is a bad way to control.

Comment: No, this will not be in a computer.
Why would it not start up reliably? Because the battery wouldn't have full effect?

How would a good way to control be?

Comment: That won't work at all because of R3 being in between the fan and BAT1 minus.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to determine the ballpark for your potentiometers using Ohm's Law (U=R*i) and then fine tune empirically (also to check if you can start the fan reliably).

Fan is rated for 5V 200mA. Realistically it will be less than 200mA but.. we'll use this figure.

For 20 Ohm:

Voltage drop < 0.2A * 20 < 0.4V

For 100 Ohm:

Voltage drop < 0.2A * 100 < 2.0V

Again, **in practice the voltage drops will be way less because current will be less than 200mA**, but there's no way to know how much it will be, hence "less than" instead of equal to. So, you might want higher resistances.

Make sure you use potentiometers rated for your current consumption.

P = R * i * i = 100R * 0.2 * 0.2 = 4W (maybe worst case)

For 20 Ohm: 20 * 0.2 *0.2 = 0.8W

Usually, pots are rated for 0.5~1W, so you really need to test all of this empirically. If you need to drop more voltage you can add a series resistor (R3) with the pot to share the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPU5Sa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

p.s.: if you are running this on a power bank and energy efficiency is important, you should really look into other methods of control, such as PWM.

Comment: The application for this is to reduce fog on my protection goggles (playing Airsoft and Paintball). A playing session can potentially last up to a day, but usually it only lasts around 30 minutes. Sure, a power bank cost money, but you have to consider my inexperience as well. I probably can't solve this using a more advanced solution unless I get a complete and fully functional specification of components needed.

Comment: @Göran -- It might be ok. 7000mAh/200mA = 35hr, so even if its 50% of its rating it seems plenty for a day. Unless fan ratings or powerbank ratings are way, way off (which isn't uncommon for random cheap power banks).

Comment: @Göran -- have you tried just wiring the fan directly to the power bank? Its airflow doesnt seem to be that high..

Comment: @Göran: You can easily solve your problem by going with a much simpler [**solution**](https://www.google.com/search?q=prevent+glasses+fogging+up&oq=Prevent+glasses+fogging&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.11299j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Wesley Lee: I work at a store that sells computer parts and getting my hands on good power banks for a good value won't be a problem. Even if the ratings would be WAY off, I could still bring two or three power banks with me in my kit. ;)
I have a working prototype that is running on 3.36 V right now, and it works great. The airflow is way over what is necessary and the noise is as well. That's why I'm thinking a high and low setting would work well.

Comment: @EM Fields: Trust me, there are a lot of different methods of solving this. Anything from putting baby shampoo on the lenses to buying expensive goggles for 150+ USD. Although I haven't tried the expensive goggles myself, others have and they are not always impressed.
An optician that plays Airsoft wrote somewhere that it doesn't matter what works for you, the next person has a different bone structure which may make the same solution not work for them.
All I know is that this works for me. :)

Comment: I believe computer fans (brushless) are normally powered via pwm at the rated voltage, rather than reducing the voltage. A 555 timer and mosfet could do this easily.

Comment: @RyanGriggs -- Yes, most of the recent ones have a dedicated pin for the PWM signal, so the FET wouldn't be needed. I was just suggesting a solution close to what the OP started with.